Error en Intellijei Idea - WildFly - Ubuntu
estoy trabajando sobre Ubuntu 24.04 y a la hora de crear mi aplicación de Jakarta EE en su version 10 e iniciar el servicio con Wildfly me da el siguiente error.

E investigado pero no e podido solucionar el problema, cabe aclarar que estoy trabajando con el IDE de Intellij Idea no se si el editor tenga algo que ver.
Me podrian ayudar con este error se lo agradeceria mucho.
Gracias!

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.
